# May an Islamic state legislate the death penalty for non-sharia crimes?

Tags: sharia, islamic-government, hudud

Countries like Saudi Arabia have a number of capital offenses, some of which seem to extend beyond sharia law; e.g. the list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_Saudi_Arabia) includes "espionage" and "drug smuggling".

However, I don't know how accurate it is, and I'm unsure if the Saudi government has Islamic justifications for these laws (perhaps they do, and I'm simply unaware).  I'm also interested in a situation in an [Islamic state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_state), not just how it's implemented in a particular country.

**Question**: May an Islamic state legislate the death penalty for non-sharia crimes?

By non-sharia crimes, I mean crimes that are not justified Islamically in one way or another.

Comment: The concept used to apply these punishments is ta'zir https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tazir

Comment: Drug smuggling and espionage are offenses in sharia (though not under those specific terms), so they may not be the best examples of "non-sharia crimes" here.